# Why is function not returning array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, function, return

I'm making a small script to calculate the Fibonacci sequence by having an array to give how many digits i want, I just can't figure out why my `fib` function is saying that there is no array being returned.

Code:

```
class Fibonacci{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] startArray = {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int[] resultArray = fib(startArray);
        
        System.out.println("Iterative Ausgabe des Fibonacci-Arrays:");
        printIterativ(resultArray);
        
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.println("Rekursive Ausgabe des Fibonacci-Arrays:");
        printRekursiv(resultArray);
    }
    
    public static int[] fib(int[] array){
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i+1] = array[i] + array[i-1];
        return array;
        }
    }
    
    public static void printIterativ(int[] array) {
        System.out.println(array);
    }

    public static void printRekursiv(int[] array) {
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this for "needing debugging details", the question contains everything (and more) to find the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please paste the exact error message into your question. It will help more than *there is no array being returned.* (@Stultuske: I didn’t downvote.) If you can, also tell from which line in the code you get the message.

Comment: @OleV.V. it's badly worded, but " my fib function is saying that there is no array being returned." tells me his compiler complains there is no return statement for the fib method. Seeing as the fib method is only 6 lines long, it isn't that difficult to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static int[] fib(int[] array){
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i+1] = array[i] + array[i-1];
        return array;
        }
    }
```

It's a matter of scopes. Your only return statements is within the for loop, but if your for loop never executes, there is no return statement.

So:

```
 public static int[] fib(int[] array){
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i+1] = array[i] + array[i-1];
        return array;
        }
    return array;
    }
```

or

```
 public static int[] fib(int[] array){
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i+1] = array[i] + array[i-1];
        }
        return array; 
    }
```

would work, because they have return statements for all scenario's. You'll need to figure out which one meets your requirements.
But, since you don't actually call fib anywhere, you might also delete the method.

Comment: One_Sleeve, if you had indented your code properly, it would have been clearer to see that this was the problem — for us and for yourself. So next time please take care to indent the code you post to Stack Overflow. Your IDE can do it for you.